# Risk of using contentEditable in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, contenteditable

We have to add a basic HTML editor to our product.  As we only support IE at present (most customers are still on IE 6), I have been told to use the Internet Explorer built-in XHTML editing capabilities – e.g. `<div contentEditable="true">` as explained at "[Editing a Web Page](http://www.maconstateit.net/tutorials/JSDHTML/JSDHTML12/jsdhtml12-02.htm)" .

**Apart** from not working in other browsers. (The management does not consider it being a problem.  Our customers will put up with our software only working with IE.  We have never lost any money by our software only working in IE; most customers will only let their staff use IE6 at present anyway)

What **other** problem are we likely to get with contentEditable?

---

**Update**

The HTML editor I wrote with “contentEditable” proved to very hard to get reliable,  with many [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527866/why-is-contenteditable-removing-id-from-div).  If I had to do this again, I would push **very hard** to one of the many open source solutions (e.g. TinyMCE) or buy in a supported HTML editor.

No doubt that a very skilled jscript programmer can get “contentEditable” to work well given enough time.  It just that all the examples on the web looks so simple, until you test common operations like doing a cut/paste from word and trying to edit the resulting HTML.  (just the sort of things a customer will do)

(Just search for “contentEditable” on stackoverflow to get some ideal of the problems other people have had)

Comment: +1 for telling people how problematic contenteditable can be.

Comment: It seems contenteditable should be "stable" by now, but there are still problems. For example, dynamic content can *really* break the html code whenever you cut-paste, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19871978/html5-contenteditable-with-dynamic-content

Comment: @NoBugs, Content pasted from word then not being editable was the case that drove me mad!  Word created *legal* HTML that was to complex contentEditable to cope with.

Comment: @IanRingrose Interesting, in what browser was that? Could you give an example?

Comment: @NoBugs, it was a long time ago, I recall the IE had problems, it may have been IE6 that a lot of our customers used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The contentEditable property works in Safari, Firefox 3, and Opera 9.

Since manipulation will undoubtably be through selections, your biggest problem will be getting the selection/ranges working across browsers ([see here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361130/get-selected-text-and-selected-nodes-on-a-page/364476#364476).

There are also numerous [little bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=454191) across browsers which may or may not bite you. These include incompatible case-sensitivity, incompatible methods of turning it off again (removeAttribute vs. setting to false).

Despite these flaws, I find it works rather well.

Answer (score 6):

How about using some open-source solution that works in all major browsers?

[TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)

There are other projects as well, but that's what I'd use.

Comment: Thanks, We have considered TinyMCE however it’s licence would need to be considered by management and there may also be legal costs on getting the licence checked out.  So I have to use contentEditable="true" unless I can find a good reason for not using it.

Answer (score 6):

[HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html) include the contenteditable attribute, so it looks like it will be in IE for a long time to come.

Just got a email from someone on the IE team

> While it's basically impossible to
>   comment on the future with a high
>   degree of confidence, it's fair to say
>   that I'm not aware of any plans to
>   remove contentEditable, and if it were
>   removed, it would break a LOT of
>   sites.

Comment: So you let IE Devs stay alive?

Comment: contenteditable seems widely supported... however, events on that contenteditable seem to be widely inconsistent (ie)...

Answer (score 3):

A quick google search produced a [blog post](http://annevankesteren.nl/2005/07/more-contenteditable) on some (albeit minor) issues of contentEditable.

Answer (score 1):

contentEditable works under Firefox 3.
I don't know of any problems with contentEditable.

Answer (score 1):

I would just be sure to check what content you get back as inserting XSS attacks are quite easy in IE if there is no validation of the HTML content added.

Comment: assuming it's used in untrusted environment

Comment: Are there issues with security if I'm using the `strip_tags` function prior to storing the data, and only permitting `<b><strong><i><em><u>`?