# How to make an HTML <div> element editable cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, contenteditable

Do you know how to make a `<div>` editable with JavaScript? I'm looking for cross-browser solution.

Something similar to a rich text area, but that uses an editable `<iframe>`. I need something similar for a `<div>`.
*I don't want to use a replacement textbox.*

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/saving-contenteditable-content-changes-as-json-with-ajax/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

I found out how.

You use the contentEditable property of the DOMElement, like so

```
<div onClick="this.contentEditable='true';">
    lorem ipsum dolor lorem ipsum dolorlorem ipsum dolor
</div>
```

Comment: Yes my friend, it really does work in Internet Explorer 6 ! Here is more info on this subject and the risks of using it in older versions of Internet Explorer. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491790/risk-of-usingcontenteditable-in-ie

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just set the attribute `contenteditable=true`, without the `onClick`? Or did/does IE not support that when this was answered?

Comment: It's actually property of HTMLElement. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable

Answer (score 19):

You can do this in pure HTML

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    Editable text...
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP wants to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: @Gothdo Actually this is the way to do this, no need of JS. Using the accepted answer, you have to click **twice** on the div to edit it the first time. Here the div appears as an ordinary div until you click it where it becomes editable.

Answer (score 6):

Set [`contentEditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable) property of the element to `"true"`:

```
element.contentEditable = "true";
```

See also:

- [Content Editable MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)
- [Browser support on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable)

Answer (score -1):

```
How about his:
```

Make a hidden "textArea" , and upon selecting(clicking or Hover) the div , hide the Div and  Show the textArea .

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want to do. Thanks.

Comment: It was way back, but as still getting some -down vote, IMHO  

"I don't want to use a replacement textbox."

Was not added when I posted this possible alternative .