# Textarea maximum characters can stored?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I am stuck in a problem,
storing more than 60,000 words in Textarea(chrome) browsers hang.
any solution?
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600398/large-text-in-textarea-freezes-computer

Comment: I tried for `200000` characters and its working fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/rnbxskgz/). Please share more information like attached events