# How to handle large data rendering on a <textarea> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

There is a websocket connection between my browser and the server. It works fine in normal cases but if the server keep sending string messages to the browser and the browser append the coming messages on a  tag. The browser will be stuck. In that case, I can't see the latest message on the textarea. I have to wait for a few minutes in order to see them. Is there a way to handle this kind of scenario?

Comment: Do you use javascript or GWT for that?

Comment: I am using GWT for that.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced issues with performance when dealing with large strings or shared Objects. You should check out [large-text-in-textarea-freezes-computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600398/large-text-in-textarea-freezes-computer) as they show the same solutions that I did the past.