# Initiate update from list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've got a partial view that lists details about my entities.  Details include a photo, caption, date, and name.  There is an ActionLink for Delete that removes the item from the list.

I would like to make the Caption field an editable textbox to allow the user to edit the contents.  Then I wold like to add an 'Update' link that will write this data to the DB.  This is the only attribute that can be edited.

Basically I want to avoid the user having to open an 'Edit' form to change this field.  I would like to be able to do it from within the list.  Not sure how to create the 'Update' ActionLink, send it to the controller, and have the user-entered text available to the controller method.

Comment: Don't use an action link if you're deleting something!  see this
[Why should you delete using an HTTP POST or DELETE, rather than GET?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786070/why-should-you-delete-using-an-http-post-or-delete-rather-than-get

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems to be an extremely basic edit, I would just put the Caption in a `Div` then using CSS/jQuery display an [edit button (glyphicon glyphicon-pencil)](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons) on mouseover.  On click set the Div to [Editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188581/how-to-make-a-div-editable-cross-browser) (use styling to show it's in edit mode, and only exit edit mode with a save button).  On save, do a jQuery Ajax call to update the value in the database.

Please be extra cautious to not have any [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) as editable content could contain anything from a user.

CSS might look like:

```
.editor editor-display button
{
  display: none;
}
.editor editor-display:hover .edit-button
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.editor editor-edit .edit-button
{
  display: none;
}
.editor editor-edit .save-button
{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Html might look like:

```
<div class="my-entity editor editor-display" data-id="5" >
<div class="edit-content">@model.Caption</div>
<button id="edit-caption-button" class="edit-button" />
<button id="save-caption-button" class="save-button" />
<div>
```

Javascript might look like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#save-caption-button").on("click", function()
  {
    $(this).parent("editor").removeClass("editor-display").addClass("editor-edit");
  });

  $("#save-caption-button").on("click", function()
  {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/MyEditity/UpdateCaption",
      data: { id: $(this).parent(".my-entity").data("id"),
        caption: $(this).parent(".my-entity").find(".edit-content").first().text() };
    });
    $(this).parent("editor").removeClass("editor-edit").addClass("editor-display");
  });
});
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult UpdateCaption(int id, string caption)
{
  // lookup entity by id
  // change caption value
  // save
  return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This is a super basic (UNTESTED!) example, with no exception handling.

Comment: That sounds like the approach I am looking for.  The jquery ajax implementation is beyond me.  Can you provide an example or reference to accomplish this?

Comment: This is great.  The 'Save' button jquery is working as expected, but I can't get the 'edit' button to make the div editable.  The javascript function is being bound to the button correctly (i put an 'alert' in, so I know it's being recognized), but the css classes are not being changed properly.

Answer (score 0):

The model that you pass to the view is of a certain type(of item in db). So, if You change the label with name "Caption" to a textbox of the same name, then the binding would remain the same - the output would be a textbox with the caption taken from the model passed to the View in Controller Action.

As for the update link:
I would create an Action of the same name as the View with [HttpPost] attribute and the model as parameter. The action would be invoked by a submit button in View (so all the labels and the textbox should be enclosed in a form). Inside that action perform the db update.

So:
The View should be something like this:

```
@model db.Foo
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <fieldset>
    @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.Name)
    (...)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Caption)
<input type="submit" value="Update Caption"/>
    </fieldset>
    }
```

and the controller actions:

```
//The action that passes the model to the View
public ActionResult Details()
        {
//
//get foo here
//
            return View(foo); //Where foo is the item You use for your model
        }
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(foo model)
        {
//
//Update model here with model of type foo
//
        }
```

Hope this helps