# Output <textarea> content as browser rendered HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wp-editor

I'm building a WordPress plugin which will allow front-end users to submit their answers via WYSIWYG initialized with `wp_editor()`, meanwhile on the back-end there will be a tutor, who will be able to access WYSIWYG submitted content and edit it.

The problem I faced on this stage is using multiple instances of `wp_editor()` on the back-end (there not functioning properly is there are more than one of them).
So after some research for fixing this I came to idea not to use `wp_editor()` on the back-end at all, and use `<textarea>` instead.

Now my question is if there **is a way to output `<textarea>` content as browser rendered HTML?**

For example, if my string is '`<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>`', I want the output to be inside my `<textarea>` like:

- One
- Two
- Three

Curious, if it's possible without long PHP and JS. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: The textarea element contains text, not HTML. For what you want to do, you want to use dynamic HTML, likely an editable div.

Comment: yeah, that's right. It may be any other container, maybe div is even more suitable.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188581/how-to-make-an-html-div-element-editable-cross-browser

Comment: thanks, guys) @apokryfos,I think your advice is a way I should approach to resolving my task