# How to make a custom element that appends each character in a <span>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm attempting to implement this functionality for a typing website so that every character that is entered will be enclosed in a span. However, I was unable to figure out how to make a custom text-editable `<div>` instead of a `<textarea>`.

Here is how the output should look.

```
<div className="typableCustomDiv">
    <span>H</span>
    <span>E</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>L</span>
    <span>O</span>
</div>
```

The reason why I want to enclose them in a span to imitate a `<textarea>` is for the following reasons:

1. Incorrect characters will have a strikethrough and be colored red.
2. Green will be used to highlight the correct characters.
3. Create a transition such that each character you type should appear gradually, with an ease of 0.25 seconds from opacity 0 to 1.
4. etc.

Comment: It´s a bit unclear what exactly you are asking.  

If you are asking for how to make a <div> element editable it has been answered here on SO over here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/28485008/5383921](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28485008/5383921)  

It´s pretty simple - just set the contenteditable attribute to true and you are done.  
[https://codepen.io/Brianmanden/pen/QWowYQG](https://codepen.io/Brianmanden/pen/QWowYQG)  


If this does not answer your question can you please elaborate in more detail what it is you are looking for.

Comment: @BrianAndersen I have tried that approach, but I came across a lot of issues such as the caret is staying at the left most side of the spans (the spans were text that is converted into spans and appended into the div) as well as the spans are being appended reversely, like this --> |elloH. I already tried debugging it, but I can't figure it out. If it is okay, can you provide us a code for it ? It will be very helpful for the community, thank you!

Comment: I don´t have any code for it.  
Feel free to clone the codepen I linked to and show us what you got. Then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

previous code the text was entered in wrong order and the cursor is on the left fixed and backspace

```js
const typableCustomDiv = document.getElementById('typableCustomDiv');
let inputText = '';

typableCustomDiv.addEventListener('input', handleInput);
typableCustomDiv.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

function handleInput(event) {
  const typedCharacter = event.data;

  if (typedCharacter) {
    inputText += typedCharacter;
  }

  updateDisplayedContent();
}

function handleKeyDown(event) {
  //backspace cleanup
  if (event.key === 'Backspace') {
    // Handle backspace key
    inputText = inputText.slice(0, -1);
    updateDisplayedContent();
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function updateDisplayedContent() {
  typableCustomDiv.innerHTML = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < inputText.length; i++) {
    const charSpan = document.createElement('span');
    charSpan.textContent = inputText[i];

    // Let's demonstrate, every 3rd char is wrong
    const isIncorrect = i % 3 === 0;
    const isCorrect = !isIncorrect;

    if (isCorrect) {
      charSpan.classList.add('correct', 'fade-in');
    } else {
      charSpan.classList.add('incorrect', 'fade-in');
    }

    typableCustomDiv.appendChild(charSpan);
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.typableCustomDiv {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.5rem;
  direction: rtl;
}

.correct {
  color: green;
}

.incorrect {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: red;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fadeIn 0.25s ease forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="typableCustomDiv" class="typableCustomDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, there is a problem with this code. As I mentioned in my earlier comment, the caret stays at the left most portion of the div, and it inputs the string backwards like this --> |olleH. The fadeIn effect also is applied to the entire text instead of the last added or deleted text.

Comment: see the updated code "direction: rtl;" and backspace clean up. is that it ?