# HTML5 ContentEditable with dynamic content?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, contenteditable, wordpress-3.5

I noticed that most TinyMCE plugins give placeholders with a simple image, and perhaps some edit-button-popover functionality. Take the Wordpress gallery and image edit functionality as an example - a simple image with edit/delete buttons. Even NextGen 2 (a few versions ago at least) had Nextgen-gallery slideshow placeholder as a simple image, not rotating image.

I was recently trying to make some more dynamic content within the editor. It's a challenge to insert the jQuery, then import the jQuery-plugins that run certain behavior within a placeholder. It's also challenging to fix the no-drag-into-noneditable-placeholder bug, after enabling the TinyMCE-noneditable plugin.

Even after that, there is a problem where the div with special content (noneditable placeholder) can lose its elements when it is drag-dropped within other text to another part of the editor.

Are things like this the reason most TinyMCE plugins make a styled image, at best? Is TinyMCE and [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable) in general inherently incompatible with jQuery-plugins running within its editors? Are there any examples of successful live preview functionality in [content-editable areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable), rather than a static image file?

***Update***

It looks like this isn't even a TinyMCE problem - as you can see on [this demo page](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php), when you add the `contenteditable="true"` attribute to the `id="main"` element, then select some text including the rotating banner, cut and paste to another part, it not only stops the slideshow (as you would expect), it also removes several img elements. Is there any way to stop this glitch?

Comment: I think at best content Editable cope with very simple HTML