# How to check in Javascript if one element is contained within another

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I check if one DOM element is a child of another DOM element? Are there any built in methods for this? For example, something like:

```
if (element1.hasDescendant(element2))
```

or

```
if (element2.hasParent(element1))
```

If not then any ideas how to do this? It also needs to be cross browser. I should also mention that the child could be nested many levels below the parent.

Comment: You should use http://stackoverflow.com/a/18234150/1868545

Comment: I believe that as JS is nowadays a "live standard" the accepted answer should be rechecked to state "conatins" method as the accepted answer.

Comment: use `Node.contains(element)` i think it solves the problem

Answer (score 307, accepted):

**Update:** There's now a native way to achieve this. [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains). Mentioned in comment and below answers as well.

**Old answer:**

Using the [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.parentNode) property should work. It's also pretty safe from a cross-browser standpoint. If the relationship is known to be one level deep, you could check it simply:

```
if (element2.parentNode == element1) { ... }
```

If the the child can be nested arbitrarily deep inside the parent, you could use a function similar to the following to test for the relationship:

```
function isDescendant(parent, child) {
     var node = child.parentNode;
     while (node != null) {
         if (node == parent) {
             return true;
         }
         node = node.parentNode;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is that the child could be nested many levels below the parent.

Comment: @AJ: I updated my answer to include a solution that should work for nesting the child arbitrarily deep in the parent.

Comment: If anyone is coming to this now it may be possible for you to use Node.contains (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.contains) which is a native function in modern browsers.

Comment: I [posted a simple one-line variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18162093/588079) (neither adding or omitting functionality compared to your answer) as answer, because properly explaining that line is unfeasible as a comment.

Comment: @JohnCarrell There is `Node.contains` (no caniuse page though)

Comment: @Asaph Could you please update your answer to include the new `Node.contains`? :)

Comment: This works but is useless because their is a native way: `parent.contains(child)`

Comment: @AdamHeath you should propose this as another answer

Answer (score 454):

You should use `Node.contains`, since it's now standard and available in all browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains

```
const parent = document.getElementById("my-parent")
const child = document.getElementById("my-child")
parent.contains(child)
```

an example of a "hasParent" function that would return if any elements are a parent:

```
const hasParent = (element, ...parents) => parents.some((parent) => parent.contains(element))

hasParent(child, parent1, parent2, parent3)
```

Comment: The Node.hasParent(parent) method is unnecessary but would be Node.prototype.hasParent=function(element){return element.contains(this);};

Comment: you could've at least added an example

Comment: This is good answear but example would be real nice: `var parent = document.getElementById('menu');
var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
if (parent.contains(allElements[i]) { alert('Link is inside meni'); }`

Comment: Offcourse you need to loop throu elements if you need to check all of them:
for (var i=0;i<allElements.length;i++) { if (parent.contains(allElements[i]) { true } }

Comment: Yeah I'd say the mozilla "example" out there clears up nothing, explicitly returns vs implicitly returns? Bunch of gobblygook rather than an actual example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Comment: One gotcha I didn't see mentioned is that `Node.contains` includes the node itself. So if you truly want to check whether a node is the child of another node, you also need to check that it's not the original node: `parentNode.contains(childNode) && parentNode !== childNode`.

Answer (score 49):

I just had to share 'mine'.

Although conceptually the same as [Asaph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234986/588079) (benefiting from the same cross-browser compatibility, even IE6), it is a *lot* smaller and comes in handy when size is at a premium and/or when it is not needed so often.

```js
function childOf(/*child node*/c, /*parent node*/p){ //returns boolean
  while((c=c.parentNode)&&c!==p); 
  return !!c; 
}
```

..or as one-liner (*just 64 chars*!):

```js
function childOf(c,p){while((c=c.parentNode)&&c!==p);return !!c}
```

and [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/C76xb/).

---

***Usage:***
`childOf(child, parent)` returns boolean `true`|`false`.

***Explanation:***
`while` evaluates as long as the while-condition evaluates to `true`.
The `&&` (AND) operator returns this boolean true/false *after* evaluating the left-hand side and the right-hand side, but only *if* the left-hand side was true *(`left-hand && right-hand`)*.

The left-hand side (of `&&`) is: `(c=c.parentNode)`.
This will first assign the `parentNode` of `c` to `c` and then the AND operator will evaluate the resulting `c` as a boolean.
Since `parentNode` returns `null` if there is no parent left and `null` is converted to `false`, the while-loop will correctly stop when there are no more parents.

The right-hand side (of `&&`) is: `c!==p`.
The `!==` comparison operator is '*not* exactly equal to'. So if the child's parent isn't the parent (you specified) it evaluates to `true`, but if the child's parent *is* the parent then it evaluates to `false`.
So *if* `c!==p` evaluates to false, then the `&&` operator returns `false` as the while-condition and the while-loop stops. (Note there is no need for a while-body and the closing `;` semicolon is required.)

So when the while-loop ends, `c` is either a node (not `null`) when it found a parent OR it is `null` (when the loop ran through to the end without finding a match).

Thus we simply `return` that fact (converted as boolean value, instead of the node) with: `return !!c;`: the `!` (`NOT` operator) inverts a boolean value (`true` becomes `false` and vice-versa).
`!c` converts `c` (node or null) to a boolean before it can invert that value. So adding a second `!` (`!!c`) converts this false *back* to true (which is why a double `!!` is often used to 'convert anything to boolean').

---

**Extra:**
The function's body/payload is so small that, depending on case (like when it is not used often and appears just once in the code), one *could* even omit the function (wrapping) and just use the while-loop:

```
var a=document.getElementById('child'),
    b=document.getElementById('parent'),
    c;

c=a; while((c=c.parentNode)&&c!==b); //c=!!c;

if(!!c){ //`if(c)` if `c=!!c;` was used after while-loop above
    //do stuff
}
```

instead of:

```js
var a=document.getElementById('child'),
    b=document.getElementById('parent'),
    c;

function childOf(c,p){while((c=c.parentNode)&&c!==p);return !!c}

c=childOf(a, b);    

if(c){ 
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: @SolomonUcko:  The strict equality comparison (`!==`) can improve speed by making it clear to the compiler that it can skip type-checking and optional implicit conversion steps that would occur in a loose equality comparison, thus improving speed (by more accurately describing what we want to happen, which is also beneficial to the programmer). I also seem to recall from when I wrote this, that just the loose comparison (`!=`) was either very error-prone or didn't work at all in some older browser(s) (I suspect it was in IE6, but I have forgotten).

Answer (score 33):

Another solution that wasn't mentioned:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/xa397p29/)

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

if (parent.querySelector('.child') !== null) {
    // .. it's a child
}
```

It doesn't matter whether the element is a direct child, it will work at any depth.

---

Alternatively, using the [`.contains()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.contains):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/ugftmfLp/)

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent'),
    child = document.querySelector('.child');

if (parent.contains(child)) {
    // .. it's a child
}
```

Comment: Your first proposed solution has very bad performance without necessity: The querySelector('.child') has to traverse the entire subtree below parent to collect all matching children. Traversing from a known child element upwards is way faster.

Comment: @MartinLisowski — look at the performance benchmarks. You are wrong.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [contains method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

`var result = parent.contains(child);`

or you can try to use [compareDocumentPosition()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition)

`var result = nodeA.compareDocumentPosition(nodeB);`

The last one is more powerful: it return a bitmask as result.

Answer (score 22):

Take a look at [Node#compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.compareDocumentPosition).

```
function isDescendant(ancestor,descendant){
    return ancestor.compareDocumentPosition(descendant) & 
        Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINS;
}

function isAncestor(descendant,ancestor){
    return descendant.compareDocumentPosition(ancestor) & 
        Node.DOCUMENT_POSITION_CONTAINED_BY;
}
```

Other relationships include `DOCUMENT_POSITION_DISCONNECTED`, `DOCUMENT_POSITION_PRECEDING`, and `DOCUMENT_POSITION_FOLLOWING`.

Not supported in IE<=8.

Comment: interesting! This reminds me of a JS function I developed on year 2003... Took me some days and got help of some JS developers... Incredible (and sad) that nowadays there's still no full drag-drop nor object-fit full browser implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `closest('.selector')`

It returns null if neither element nor any of its ancestors matches the selector. Alternatively returns the element which was found

Answer (score 3):

I came across a wonderful piece of code to check whether or not an element is a child of another element. I have to use this because IE doesn't support the `.contains` element method. Hope this will help others as well.

**Below is the function:**

```
function isChildOf(childObject, containerObject) {
  var returnValue = false;
  var currentObject;

  if (typeof containerObject === 'string') {
    containerObject = document.getElementById(containerObject);
  }
  if (typeof childObject === 'string') {
    childObject = document.getElementById(childObject);
  }

  currentObject = childObject.parentNode;

  while (currentObject !== undefined) {
    if (currentObject === document.body) {
      break;
    }

    if (currentObject.id == containerObject.id) {
      returnValue = true;
      break;
    }

    // Move up the hierarchy
    currentObject = currentObject.parentNode;
  }

  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I literally tried every other polyfill on this page including .contains, and this is the only one that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Via selector

A use case I had to work with isn't checking if an element is child of another specific element, but if an element is a child of a kind of element expressed by a selector. In such a case nowadays we can use [Element.matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches). Here is an example for a use case.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (ev)=>{
    if(ev.target.matches(".kind-of-el *")){
        console.log("click within 'kind-of-el'") 
    }
    
})
```

The other direction should also be possible in modern browsers. So to answer if an element has children with class 'kind-of-el' we can just check

```js
if(el.matches(":has(.kind-of-el)")){
    console.log("el has a descendant with class 'kind-of-elzz'")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
x = document.getElementById("td35");
if (x.childElementCount > 0) {
    x = document.getElementById("LastRow");
    x.style.display = "block";
}
else {
    x = document.getElementById("LastRow");
    x.style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: a library**

I advise using something like [dom-helpers](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers), written by the react team as a regular JS lib.

In their [contains implementation](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/dom-helpers/blob/master/src/contains.ts) you will see a [Node#contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) based implementation with a [Node#compareDocumentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/compareDocumentPosition) fallback.

Support for very old browsers e.g. IE <9 would not be given, which I find acceptable.

This answer incorporates the above ones, however I would advise against looping yourself.