# How to detect clicks outside of scope in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a angular controller which needs to reset whenever the user clicks outside the scope of the controller. How do I do this?

Sample html:

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div id='1' ng-controller="ctrl1">
        <!--other things-->
    </div>

    <div id='2' ng-controller="ctrl2">
        <!--other things-->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent2">
        <!--other things-->
</div>
```

I want to be able to reset ctrl2 if a click occurs outside of `ctr2` when the click occurs outside of div2

ctr2 has a reset function defined inside

Answer (score 4):

If you are wanting a reset when the click happens within a sibling div, then the fact that the controllers share `$scope` should make that fairly straightforward.  If you want to reset the div when a click happens *anywhere else on the page,* then you should set the "resetting" div as a directive, binding the `$window` object to a click handler:

```
app.directive('reset', function($window){
  return {
    template: '<div ng-class="{red: directiveToggler}">I\'m in 2' +
              ' - click me to turn red, click anywhere else to turn me normal'+
              '</div>',
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.directiveToggler = true;
  },
  link: function(scope, element){

    var w = angular.element($window);
    w.bind('click', function(e){

      if (e.target != element[0].children[0]){
        scope.directiveToggler = false;
        scope.$apply();

      } else {
        scope.directiveToggler = true;
        scope.$apply()
      }
    })
  }
  }
})
```

Note that there are probably waaay better ways of handling the class/style changes than what I have set up, but the question was about click events ;).

[Here's a plunk to demo](http://plunker.co/edit/RPmGOqOtO6k1wuzzL1H8?p=preview)

Comment: I combined your answer with http://stackoverflow.com/a/17338860/130641 for a multi-element directive solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$rootScope` to broadcast events to other controllers. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/XqDxG/

Comment: So there is no way to do it from within the controller? I was thinking of using $window service.

Comment: [`$window`](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.$window) is just encapsulating the browser's `window` object.