# Accessing an element and its children/descendants in a window click event

Tags: javascript, events

In my window event, if the pointer clicks on the parent or its child/descendant, it should do something.
The problem is the event can't access the parent's child and grand child. The condition is stored in the `targetIsInsideParent` variable.

HTML

```
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="grandchild">
      GrandChild
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const targetIsParent = e.target === parent;
  const targetIsInsideParent = e.target === parent.children; // !!!!

  if(targetIsParent || targetIsInsideParent) {
    console.log('Good');
  }
})
```

Comment: You have to use the `parent` chain of the target, iterating to see if one of the links is the parent element.

Comment: @Pointy Use an Iterator?

Comment: Well if an element is a descendant of the parent, then either it's `.parent` references the parent, or the `.parent` of the parent, etc.

Comment: You could also just check to see if the target matches `.parent *` via the `.matches()` API.

Comment: You're asking if the target is the same as the child of the parent, which it's not. it's the grand child. `parent.childElementCount` is 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check in Javascript if one element is contained within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-contained-within-another)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `parent.contains(e.target)` or `parent.compareDocumentPosition(e.target) === 20`

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');

window.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const targetIsParent = e.target === parent;
  const targetIsInsideParent = parent.contains(e.target);
  // const targetIsInsideParent = parent.compareDocumentPosition(e.target) === 20; // alternative, but also works good
  if(targetIsParent || targetIsInsideParent) {
    console.log('Good');
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  Parent
  <div class="child">
    Child
    <div class="grandchild">
      GrandChild
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Other</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very helpful. But which should I prefer between `.contains()` and `.compareDocumentPosition()` when it comes to performance and browser support?

Comment: I would suggest `.contains()` because of it is little bit better supported, shorter, and I guess, that it should work faster, because it checks only `node` inner content, while `compareDocumentPosition` checks not only childs and subchilds, but also parent siblings and `node`'s parents