# forwarding refs to non children in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an event listener that should fire onClick, except for if you click on the navbar/an item in the navbar. 
usually, I'd handle this like this:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleOutsideClick);

handleOutsideClick = e => {
  if(!this.navREF.current.contains(e.target)){
    //do my stuff
  }
}
```

The problem is that the nav is far away from my component that has this logic and I don't really feel like passing the ref through 10+ components. Since `findDomNode` is deprecated/discouraged to use I was wondering if there was another way to handle this.

Is there a quicker way to pass my ref? I'm using redux for my other dataflow.

My worst case solution is to add a `data` attribute to every single item in my  nav but there's probably a 50% chance that that would get me fired..

Edit:
Different from other questions about the topic as the external component is outside of the scope of my react component

Comment: Your handler should fire on any click anywhere in the app except for the nav?

Comment: @FrankModica yes, modified it to clarify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect click outside React component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32553158/detect-click-outside-react-component)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to pass the ref, so instead I adapted [this abomination](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2234986/9629307)

```
  checkIfParent = e => {
    let node = e.target;
    while (node) {
      if (node.id && node.id === 'ParentId') {
        return true;
      }
      node = node.parentNode;
    }
    return false;
  };
```