# Is it possible to create a condition if a clickable element are included in a node with a certain attribute?

Tags: javascript

In the following source code, is it possible to create a JavaScript function which detects if the clickable element is in a specific node with a certain attribute.

Example:

```
<button data-type="mybutton">
  <div class="mydiv">
    <img src="">
  </div>
</button>
```

The clickable elements could be the `<img>`, `<div>`, or `<button>` tags, all  included in the `<button class='mybutton">` parent node. How can I create the condition in Javascript?

Something like this?

```
element.closest("button:data-type[mybutton]")
```

Thank you

Comment: So, you want to list all children of the `<button>`?

Comment: We have `Node.contains()` to check if a certain node is included inside another node. And we have `Element.matches()` to see if a certain node would match a specific selector string. But unless I interpret the question wrong, just `element.querySelector( 'button[data-type="mybutton"]' )` should return the element if it exists, else it returns null.

Comment: I created the following JS function within Google Tag Manager: 
if ({{Click Element}}.querySelector("button[data-type='mybutton']") != null) { myvalue = "ok"; } else { myvalue = "notok" ; }

It looks not properly working, and when I'm testing it with the Chrome Console : 
console.log({{Click Element}}.querySelector("button[data-type='mybutton']"));, I always have the value null when I'm click on the different element (<img> and <button>)

Answer (score 0):

[How to check in Javascript if one element is contained within another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2234979/how-to-check-in-javascript-if-one-element-is-contained-within-another)

Using the [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) method mentioned in the link above, you should be able to do this by iterating through all candidate buttons (from [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) with the proper tag and `data-type`) and see which one contains the element you clicked.