# get a common parent for two DOM elements

Tags: jquery, dom, parent, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find the nearest common ancestors of two or more nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960843/how-to-find-the-nearest-common-ancestors-of-two-or-more-nodes)

I have 2 anchor elements and i need to get the common parent of 2 of them.

Some times they are in a ul, sometimes in a table, or any other way.

I am doing this:

```
var idParent = $(elem1).parents().filter($(elem2).parents()).first().attr('id');
```

But it doesnt always work,  i finds it element sometimes...

Any better idea? or a way to fix this?

EDIT:
I want a jquery solution.

Thank you

Comment: So you need to get a common parent for those two elements?

Comment: Yes exactly what i need, but i want a jquery solution.

Comment: The link to the possible duplicate is implemented using jQuery..?

Comment: The very first, and accepted, answer is. If that answer is not good enough, please tell us why?

Comment: The question is exactly the same. That said, the answer there wasn't great, in my opinion: I've just posted a new one.

Comment: @ Thor Jacobsen, my mistake , you are right. ill check that one

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var parent = $(elem1).parents().has(elem2).first();
```

Comment: [;-)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960843/how-to-find-the-nearest-common-ancestors-of-two-or-more-nodes/7648323#7648323)

Comment: @Roz Can you brief  how it works?