# Find parent(closest) DOM element of multiple elements

Tags: c#, html, dom

I find the solution a bit tricky and I need some help with this.
 Let's say we have 3 HTML DOM elements, how can we find the closest element that contains all this 3 elements? Is there any efficient way to achieve this?

I am using C# .net and classic System.Windows.Forms webbrowser called webBrowser1.

If the question sounds a bit hard, let me explain. We have the following HTML text:

```
<body>
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">some text</div>
  <div id="c">some text</div>
  <div id="d"> 
      <div id="e">some text</div>
      <div id="f">
           <div id="g">some text</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The first element that contains elements *B C* and *E* is **A**

The first element that contains *G* and *E* is **D**

Really hope somebody can help with this. 
 Thank you in advance

Comment: Oh man `:(` I'd love to write this in JavaScript, but it's tagged C#.

Comment: well I think I could translate to C#, as long as you can write in Javascript and using DOM it should be good :)

Comment: In that case, check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960843/how-to-find-the-nearest-common-ancestors-of-two-or-more-nodes).

Comment: OK, I'll write the JavaScript-solution later today (in ~8 hours) (I got work do do now).

Comment: The solution from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3960843/how-to-find-the-nearest-common-ancestors-of-two-or-more-nodes does help. But I find it a bit unefficient if you have an variable number of elements (not only 2). But it will do for now, thank you

Comment: More help on the issue would be appreciated. I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to achieve this. The idea is that I can have more than 2 nodes, and I need to find the common ancestor (the first node that contains all the other nodes) for all this nodes.