# How to get id from user selected text with jquery?

Tags: jquery

For example :

```
<span id=1>this is my </span><span id=2>selected text</span><span id=3> but this is not selected</span>
```

I want to catch the list of span id of the text selected by user with jquery.

In this example i want : [1,2]

thanks

Comment: Question based on supplied code doesn't make sense.  You have 3 sibling spans, but you want the IDs of the first two when one of them is selected??  Does not compute..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).cloneContents()).children("span")` will get you the selected spans. The [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) are always a good place to start for this kind of this.

Comment: BTW - you might want to read this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361130/get-selected-text-and-selected-nodes-on-a-page/364476#364476

Answer (score 0):

```
var delimitedList = '';
$('pre span').each(function() {
    delimitedList += $(this).attr('id') + ',';
});

//Remove last comma
delimitedList = delimitedList.substring(0, delimitedList.length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add a class to the spans that are supposed to be selected, like so -

```
<span id="1" class="selected">this is my </span><span id="2" class="selected">selected text</span><span id=3> but this is not selected</span>
```

And then use following jQuery -

```
var selectedByUser = $("span.selected");
```