# Checking whether selected text is part of a larger node with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a document editor using JQuery, and have implemented basic formatting: select text, click a button and the text is surrounded in the appropriate tag.

To improve this, I now need to examine the text before and after the selection, to see whether a tag has already been opened etc. Is there any simple way of checking whether the selection is a part of a larger node?

For example, if I was to select "jumps" in the following text and click, the correct behaviour would be to de-`<strong>` it, as it is already in a `<strong>` node.

```
The <strong>quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</strong>.
```

Comment: what do you mean `select` in mouse ?

Comment: this might help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361130/get-selected-text-and-selected-nodes-on-a-page

Comment: @diEcho ECMAScript implementations so far do not support lookbehind assertion nor would that help here.

Comment: @PointedEars I didnt write it

Comment: For the case of a bold button, is there a reason why you can't use `document.execCommand("bold", false, null)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To improve this, I now need to examine the text before and after the selection, to see whether a tag has already been opened etc. Is there any simple way of checking whether the selection is a part of a larger node?

(Tags are opened [in HTML, with `<`], but what you really mean is whether [an *element* has been *started*](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.1). The difference is crucial for you to understand what you are doing here.)

Because a node in the document is part of the document *tree*, and a text node can be at most the child node of one non-text node, *every* text selection is "part of a larger node".  However, whether you can find out what that node is, and whether it is *easy* to do depends both on your abilities and on the browser, as it depends on the DOM implementation used by the layout engine of the browser.

For example, in Gecko-based browsers such as Firefox and in WebCore-based browsers such as Chrome/Google Chrome, you could execute

```
var selection = window.getSelection();
```

on select.  In `selection` you would then have a reference to an object implementing the `Selection` (Gecko) or `DOMSelection` (WebCore) interface, that has properties such as `anchorNode` that refer to an object implementing the `Text` interface (see the [Gecko DOM Reference at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) for that).

That object, which represents the text node that the start of the selection is part of, has a `parentNode` property which gets you the element node object, and through its `tagName` or `nodeName` property, the element type name:

```
var textParent = selection.anchorNode.parentNode;
var textParentType = textParent.nodeName;
```

The value of `textParent.parentNode` can then be used to traverse one more level up the document tree aso.

Extra care must be taken when the `anchorNode` and `focusNode` properties refer to different text node objects, for then the selection usually spans not only several text nodes but several elements.  That is, in a table the user could have easily selected the text "foobar" as in `<td>foo</td><td>bar</td>`.

With runtime feature tests and exception handling you can determine which interface is supported without resorting to error-prone browser sniffing.

> For example, if I was to select "jumps" in the following text and click, the correct behaviour would be to de-`strong` it, as it is already in a `strong` node.

You might want to reconsider that. Perhaps you just picked a bad example, but there can be value in a `strong` element within a `strong` element; the inner element's CSS properties are not necessarily redundant.  Another example is emphasizing text already in an `em` element for which the user might want to use the `strong` element then.

Avoid jQuery; you do not need it and on closer inspection you would not even want it.

Comment: `anchorNode` and `focusNode` are not guaranteed to refer to text nodes, and for some selections in some browsers, they don't.

Comment: @TimDown Please be more specific so that I can perhaps update my answer.

Comment: OK. Open the following example in Firefox 11 and triple click the text: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/8hs45/. This is not an isolated example. As far as I know, `anchorNode` and `focusNode` are in practice limited to being elements or text nodes, although I wouldn't rule out a browser reporting them in other node types if a range with boundaries in other node types was selected.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a temporary tag to make it a selectable DOM element

```
The <strong>quick brown fox <tmp>jumps</tmp> over the lazy dog</strong>.
```

Then call parent of the temporary tag and compare it to the tag being applied.

```
var $tmp = $('tmp');
var enclosingTagType = $tmp.parent()[0].tagName;
if (enclosingTagType == requestedTagType {
  ....profit...
}
```

or even

```
$tmp.closest(requestedTagType)
```

To see if its wrapped at all...

Answer (score 0):

here , try this :

http://jsbin.com/asajuk/7/edit

```
var getSelectedNode = function ()
    {
        var node, selection;
        if (window.getSelection)
        {
            selection = getSelection();
            node = selection.anchorNode;
        }
        if (!node && document.selection)
        {
            selection = document.selection
            var range = selection.getRangeAt ? selection.getRangeAt(0) : selection.createRange();
            node = range.commonAncestorContainer ? range.commonAncestorContainer : range.parentElement ? range.parentElement() : range.item(0);
        }
        if (node)
        {
            return (node.nodeName == "#text" ? node.parentNode : node);
        }
    };
```