# Change back color of several contiguous HTML tags when user selects them

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I'm developing an Extension for Google Chrome. It has a text highlighting facility when user select  a certain text area. 
When it comes to  a single  tag I can just use a `<span>` tag inside that particular tag.
so far what i have done is below.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

   for(var d in divs) {
      // highlight a part of a <p> tag
        divs[d].addEventListener('mouseup',function(){var str= document.getSelection() ;alert(str);          
        this.innerHTML =this.innerHTML.replace(str,'<span style="background-color: '+'yellow'+' ">'+str+'</span>');
        }); 
  }
```

But if user select several tag areas (contiguous tags) how can I do it. I can't put a single `<span>` tag there. I have to  use `<span>` tag for each of those selected tags.

1) how to detect and get user selected tags. And the starting points and end points.?

2) how to change back color of them at once.?

3) do i want to add listeners , If so how should i do that ?

Any help will be appreciate .

Comment: Why don't you use a span tag outside the selection instead of within it?

Comment: I don't think i got the question you are asking correctly. I think you meant outside the tags by  'outside the selection'. 
when user select a part of a <p> tag it will only change the color of that part only (like a highlighter) so that is why i  used that.

but if user select several tags at once it can not be done that way. Do you know any way to do it ?

Comment: <span style="background-color:yellow"><p>Example code 1</p></span>
will do it , but can't use

<p><span style="background-color:yellow">Example code 1</p><p> example code 2</p></span>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2583895/96100

Answer (score 1):

I have understood the following:

- Your extension changes the background color of the text (of the underlying paragraph-nodes) the user has selected in the webpage.
- Currently your implementation adds an EventListener to inject a span tag inside a paragraph-tag

  if the Event mouseup fires.
- You would like to know how to highlight the selected area (the nodes) if the user has selected more than a single [leaf-node](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)?

Have i understood you correctly?

As far as i have understood your question you could do the following. 
If multiple nodes are selected you could set the background-color on each node within the selected text:

Based on this html:

```
<h2>How to set background color of selected text</h2>
<div>   
    <h3 id="h">This is a headline</h3>
    <p id="p1">This is the first paragraph</p>
    <p id="p2">This is the second paragraph</p>
    <button id="b1" onclick="colorSelectedNodes()">color selected nodes</button>
</div>
```

You could use the following Javascript:

```
function colorSelectedNodes(){
    var ds= document.getSelection();
    var elements = []
        // only start node if selection occured from start to end 
        // (from top left to right bottom)
    var anchorNode = ds.anchorNode.parentNode; 
    var elementSibling = anchorNode.nextElementSibling;
    var focusNode = ds.focusNode.parentNode; // endnode

    while(elementSibling.nextElementSibling){
        console.log("elementSibling", elementSibling);
        elementSibling.style.backgroundColor = "#00FFFF";           
        elementSibling.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        elementSibling.style.color = "blue";
        elementSibling = elementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
    // just to show focus and end node
    anchorNode.style.backgroundColor = "lightgreen"; 
    focusNode.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 
    console.log("anchorNode", anchorNode);
    console.log("focusNode", focusNode);
}
```

There are a few thinks to take care of

- if the user selects from end to start `anchorNode` and `focusNode` are switched,
- above i do not check if the selection is within a single node (for example inside a span) or if the selection contains many nodes
- [according to another question chrome (webkit) changed the api of `document.getSelection();`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335252/how-can-i-get-the-dom-element-which-contains-the-current-selection)
- [cross browser is a bumby ride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361130/get-selected-text-and-selected-nodes-on-a-page); but you are looking for a chrome only solution this should not be to relevant for you

I hope [my answer gets you going in the right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you have more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: :Thank you for your kind reply.You have understood my problem very well and i liked to add something you missed. I tried your code. It will change the back color of the whole tag. (and also the back color of the next tags below the selection of the code). 

Take a look at the below code. that is what i have done so far. If a user select only a part of a <p> tag that specific part only be highlighted. not the whole tag. 

<p>The E<span style="background-color:yellow">xample code </span> continues</p>

Comment: @
threeFourOneSixOneThree : So i really  wanted to know how could i change the back color if the user selection is going through several tags. so far i know to handle if user select a text area in a single <p> tag. any idea how to do it ?

Comment: i am not sure if i understand; if a user selected the text / the area  from `<h3 id="h">` up to `<p id="p2">` the background of each node should be changed. For the case that only a part within a node is selected for example `<span>unselected, i_am_selected</span>` you already found a solution. The problem you have to solve is to check if the selection contains only 1 node or many nodes.

Comment: yes but not the background of the whole tag. Only the part of that tag which the user selected(i wanted it in that way). If the selection is within a single tag i can just replace that selected string (str) with :

'<span style="background-color: '+'yellow'+' ">'+str+'</span>'

as I've mentioned in the original question.
I can't do this trick if there are many tags like <a> tags and some other <p> tags. how should i change the color of them accordingly ?

Comment: take a look at this code , `<p id="p1">This is the first paragraph</p>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/">go to facebook</a> 
<p id="p2">This is the second paragraph</p>
<p id="p3">This is the third paragraph</p>`

assume that user select the text part **'is the first'** from the first <p> tag. Then we can use my way I've mentioned. But assume  that user selected **'first paragraph go to facebook This is the second'** part of text which contain 3 tags (**go to facebook** is a link). I wanted to highlight only these text. I think now you got a better view of my problem.

Comment: thank you very much. I really needed help. If you figure it out. please let me know.