# Highlight text feature in browser (Chrome) which looks like highlighting in android

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selection

I want to implement feature (for chrome extension) which allows the user to select some text from webpage in browser with mouse and I want to add ability for the user to **edit selection boundaries** (like it can be done in android application) with small controls below the selected line which can be moved with the mouse:

[image: http://s17.postimg.org/9s9flupjj/android.png]

May be there is existing library to achieve similar behaviour in browser in easy way?

Answer (score 0):

i think this might help..

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

for(var d in divs) {
  // highlight a part of a <p> tag
    divs[d].addEventListener('mouseup',function(){var str= document.getSelection()    ;alert(str);          
    this.innerHTML =this.innerHTML.replace(str,'<span style="background-color: '+'yellow'+' ">'+str+'</span>');
    }); 
}
```

And more of it can be found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158778/change-back-color-of-several-contiguous-html-tags-when-user-selects-them)